# Recursive find and copy to other directory

Tags: linux, find, copy

I need to find all files in a directory and it's subdirectories, but I need to keep directory structure. For example there is a file

```
/media/subdir1/subdir2/file.jpg
```

and I want to copy it to

```
/new-media/subdir1/subdir2/file.jpg
```

and the same to all files inside /media/ directory. And by the way, directories inside /new-media/ must be created if not exist.

if I use

```
find /media/ -name '*.jpg' -exec cp /new-media/ ????? {} \;
```

how can I get all subdirectories inside /media/?

Comment: Is `cp -r /media /new-media` what you want? If not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above will get you everything in /media, but to get exactly what you want you probably want to use something like:

Method 1: Copy only what you need recursively, per your requirements:

```
    mkdir ../media2; find . -name "*.jpg" -exec cp -r --parents {} ../media2 \;
```

I ran this from inside the directory you want to search recursively. It does a couple things:

1 - create the new destination directory

```
    mkdir ../media2
```

2 - then finds all files ending with ".jpg" recursively.

```
    find . -name "*.jpg"
```

3 - uses -exec to pass the copy command to each file returned to find as a match, and subs that in as the first argument (which with the syntax of cp, is going to be your source file):

```
    -exec cp -r --parents {} ../media2 \;
```

the "--parents" flag retains existing directory structure and recursively creates subsequent parent directories. Super useful right?

Method 2: there might be a better way to do this with xargs, but the above ended up being the most simple method imho. That said, if you want to think outside the box, you could simply copy the entire directory over recursively, then remove anything NOT ending with ".jpg" with something like:

```
    cp -r media media2; find ./media '!'-name "*.jpg" -type f | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
cp -r /media /new-media
```

> -R, -r, --recursive
>         copy directories recursively

Hope this helps.